# Debian 9: Folders & external devices visible on desktop

Tags: debian, desktop-environment

I'm running Linux Debian 9 but I cannot make visible neither the folders and the external devices on the desktop.

The desktop environment is *Gnome*.

Browsing on Google I did not find anything helpful.

Could you help me solving this?

Thanks all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to "System Settings", click on "Desktop", in "Desktop layout" select in the drop down box "Show desktop icons on..."  A list should appear, enable/disable desktop icons for : computer, home, trash, mounted volumes, network.

I switched to gnome to verify, in terminal type:

```
    gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true  
    gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible true  
    nautilus -q  
    nautilus
```

The newest version of gnome, 3.28, doesn't support desktop icons.  To get your gnome version:

```
apt-cache show gnome-shell | grep Version
```

Comment: Hi @ptriciasaur and thanks for the comment, but I do not have the path you suggested in Linux Debian (or, at least, I did not find that). I think that your advice works for Ubuntu only.

Comment: I switched to gnome to verify:

Comment: new answer below.

Comment: Hi! I did not solved by following what you suggested; thanks any way @ptriciasaur

Comment: it worked with Debian 9. Thanks.!